# Accessing Custom Global Defines of Unity3D from source code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any way I can check in Unity whether Google Mobile Games was imported with the custom global defines?

I can't find an explanation on how the Custom Global Defines work.

I expect it to be something like this:

```
#if Admob
//Complete code here (Disabled when Google Play Games isn't imported
#endif
```

Or is there another to do this?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/4wzs9a/has_anyone_here_used_custom_global_defines_in/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Unity's Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html):

> It is possible to add to the built-in selection of #define directives by supplying your own. Open the Other Settings panel of the Player Settings and navigate to the Scripting Define Symbols text box.

In case it is not defined there, you should add your custom define manually, separating it from other defines using a `;`. Then you should be able to use your custom define like you've pointed out in your question.

You may also want to automate the setting and unsetting of custom defines by adding extra functionality to Unity3D's Editor, through the code below. This will create a menu entry in Unity's Editor, for easy access. This is quite useful when you need to frequently change a specific custom define.

The idea of this code does not belongs to me, the source of it is in [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/4wzs9a/has_anyone_here_used_custom_global_defines_in/).

E.g. for the custom define "GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES", you should write something like this:

```
public class ToggleDefineSymbol : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/Set GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES")]
    public static void Set_GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES()
    {
        string symbols = PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(
            BuildTargetGroup.Standalone);

        if (!symbols.Contains("GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES"))
        {
            PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(
                BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, symbols + ";GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES");
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/Unset GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES")]
    public static void Unset_GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES()
    {
        string symbols = PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(
            BuildTargetGroup.Standalone);

        if (symbols.Contains("GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES"))
        {
            symbols = symbols.Replace(";GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES", "");
            PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(
                BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, symbols);
        }
    }
}
```

Put this script in a folder named `Editor`, in your `Assets` folder.

You may also want to change the `BuildTargetGroup` argument according to your needs. In case you need this for further custom defines, just replicate the functions above, replacing "GOOGLE_MOBILE_GAMES" with whatever custom define you need.

Comment: Unset will not work if it is the only define for the Plattform as symbols will not contain any ';'.

Comment: An crude fix is to have both lines in unset:                 
symbols = symbols.Replace($";{FIXED_ROUTING_TESTS}", "");
symbols = symbols.Replace(FIXED_ROUTING_TESTS, "");